# Android app perform action after period of inactivity (no user interaction)

Tags: android

How can I add a timer to my Android app that is based on user interaction (or lack thereof)? In other words, if there is no user interaction for 2 minutes, I want to have the app do something, in this case navigate to the initial Page(Like Login Page). If at 1:55 someone touches the screen, the timer resets. I would think this would need to be a global timer so no matter which view you are on, the lack of interaction starts the timer. Although, I could create a unique timer on each view. Does anyone have any suggestions, links or sample code where this has been done before?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with Handler and a postDelayed runnable
something like

```
handler.postDelayed(yourRunnable, 120000);
```

and cancel it by removing if user interact with screen.

Regards,

Comment: can i  mention handler in all screens of my application?or only once throughout the app?

Comment: you will have to make it every where but you should be able to factorise this by playing with inheritence.

Comment: can you please give me full code or any other links

Comment: to use handler or to create your app?

Comment: for handler usage in android app?

Comment: add private Handler mHandler to your attributes in activities or fragment
then in oncreate : mHandler = new Handler();
and mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,YOUR_DELAY);

Comment: @LaxmanMarth : This link may help understanding handlers [Handlers in android](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-handler-example)